# VBA Error "Bubble Up"

Tags: vba, excel

I haven't read much about it, but the author at the link below recommends that I don't use "bubble up" to centralize error handling in VBA.

[Excel Programming Weekend Crash Course via Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=9dGNHE81NYIC&lpg=PT371&ots=OaUdBy4yYj&dq=VBA%20feature%20centralize%20errors%20tempting&pg=PT371#v=onepage&q=VBA%20feature%20centralize%20errors%20tempting&f=false)

But I'm not sure why he recommends that, and he doesn't really explain.

Can someone tell me why I should put error handling in EVERY procedure instead of using "bubble up"?  Or at least, do you know why the author says not to?

Thanks.

Comment: -1 Please don't use shortened URLs. Nobody likes to follow blind links at work. (+1 available upon direct link.)

Comment: That author is totally incorrect. Bubbling is a powerful and essential tool in professional VBA programming (speaking as 25-year VBA pro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the default error handling of VBA is, but since its Visual Basic for Applications, and those applications include things like excel and word, I assume just a dialog box will appear which will not be helpful to the user.

I assume that the author has been bitten by code not handling errors so he now recommends all procedures to handle errors.

The full answer is that you have to be aware of every error that can occur and to have code in place to handle it, whether it is as low as possible (where you may not know what to do), or as high as possible (which means less effort writing error handling code, but not knowing why the error occurred), or strategically (which is just in the right places where you should be able to recover from most common errors) or just everywhere (which may be just too much development effort).

Comment: VBA _does_ allow errors to bubble up.  There are exceptions, but in general, you don't have to have error-handling in every single method to prevent a jarring pop-up from the application.

Answer (score 18):

The short answer to your first question is "you *shouldn't* put an error handler in EVERY procedure". But usually *some* routines do need them!

To say that "every procedure must have an error handler" is in general terrible advice. The flaws with VBA error handling have been much discussed elsewhere. Conceptually, though, it's not all that different from the more standard form of exception handling found in other languages. Most of the best practices from those languages apply. You should handle errors at the lowest level where handling them makes sense. Sometimes this is in the procedure where the error occurred, many times not.

Often the most meaningful thing an internal routine can do when an error occurs is just let it pass on up the stack so it can reach code that knows what to do with it. It really depends on the routine and how it fits with the rest of the program.

Consider these examples:

A handler in a calling procedure will handle all errors raised by the routines it calls. So if a particular routine doesn't need any cleanup, then don't put any error-handler code there:

```
Sub Caller()
          On Error GoTo HANDLER
          ChildProc
          On Error GoTo 0
          
          Exit Sub
HANDLER:
          Debug.Print Error, "Parent cleanup - something happened in either this procedure or a procedure that it called"
End Sub


Sub ChildProc()
          Debug.Print 10 / 0  ' causes error

          'Don't bother handling errors here since there's nothing this routine can do about them
End Sub
```

On the other hand, you may need cleanup tasks, in which case you need an error handler.

```
Sub Caller()
          On Error GoTo HANDLER
          ChildProc
          On Error GoTo 0
          
          Exit Sub
HANDLER:
          Debug.Print Error, "Parent cleanup"
End Sub


Sub ChildProc()
          
          'Pretend this routine gets ahold of some resource that must be cleaned up when it's done
          call get_resources()

          On Error GoTo HANDLER
          Debug.Print 10 / 0  ' causes error
          On Error GoTo 0
          
          'Clean up once we're done
          call release_resources()
          
          Exit Sub
HANDLER:
          Debug.Print Error, "Child cleanup"
          
          'Clean up in case of an error
          call release_resources()

          'Raise another error if necessary to let callers know something went wrong
          Err.Raise 10000, "ChildProc", Error
End Sub
```

The above examples are just meant to illustrate the point about why you might need or not need an error handler in a given routine. So it's worth noting that in real code the "resource" example is usually handled better with an RAII technique where the error handling is encapsulated with the resource acquisition and release - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792280/58845 for a VBA example. And things like whether to re-raise a caught error are also situation-dependent. Sometimes it's possible to handle the error entirely locally and then there is no need to tell callers that anything went wrong.

The answer to your second question is that the author doesn't seem to understand exception handling very well. He admits that error handling is context specific, but then seems to suggest that every procedure should locally decide between "correct the problem right here and resume execution" and "terminate the program". He leaves out the usually correct option, which is "clean up locally and kick the problem upstairs". So routines with no need to clean up locally should just let errors "bubble up".

Comment: For a non-VBA example, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737328/why-should-i-not-wrap-every-block-in-try-catch/2737337#2737337

Comment: Any resources covering "kicking upstairs" please ?

Comment: @QHarr, see this answer and the links contained within...https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432413/58845

Comment: i disagree that handling should ONLY happen in the proc where it happens. There may be cleanup tasks in both the caller and the sub. Also, a handler in the top-level procedure will conveniently handle all errors in all subs.

Comment: @johnywhy, I think we agree! That's the point of my answer. The OP was asking why that book recommended putting error handling in every procedure. My view is that such advice is incorrect.

Comment: @jtolle Your original text was unclear: "you shouldn't put an error handler in every procedure". I edited for clarity and added examples.

Comment: @johnywhy, I think I see what you thought I might have meant. Thanks for the examples. I expanded on them some because in order to show more clearly why you might want or not want a local error handler.

Comment: @jtolle In the first example, this is unclear: `"something happened"`. It would be more clear and helpful to be specific: `"an error"`, not `"something"`. Also this part is confusing: `"either this procedure or a procedure that it called"` -- that's true with BOTH examples, but since you put that comment only in one example, that suggests it only holds true with that one example, which is incorrect. i wouldn't include `release_resources()`, we don't know what that means, and now a noob will be asking "what's `release_resources()`"? Better to just put a comment `"Child cleanup code here"`, IMO!

Comment: @jtolle I wouldn't say `"there's nothing this routine can do about them"`, that's inaccurate and confusing. A more accurate comment would be `"no cleanup needed"`

Comment: Yeah, but what does "cleanup" mean? I think if providing a specific example, then the distinction between "needs cleanup" and "doesn't need cleanup" should be explicit. If I think about it, that's probably why I didn't provide a code example when answering this 12(!) years ago. The principles of exception handling are pretty simple, as is the core answer to the OP - don't put EH in every routine! But the details of exactly how to handle which situations are highly routine- or application-specific. Maybe it's best if you make the exact example you want to show a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents:
You should put error handlers on all Public Procedures and Events. This means that the procedure at the bottom of the call stack will always have an error handler. Then add error handlers in your other procedures as it makes sense. If an error occurs in a procedure that does not have an error handler, it will "bubble up" to the top level error handler where it be logged/displayed in a professional fashion. 
A scenario where you might want to add an error handler to a private (lower level) procedure is this:
The code needs to be fast. You have a rare condition that can be avoided, but will force you to perform an expensive logical test inside of a loop (or worse a nested loop). 
You might perform the logical test in the error handler, and if it's said "rare occurrence" make the correction and resume. As the condition is rare, you will see performance gains for most conditions. If the error handler can't figure out and correct the problem then re-raise the error to bubble it on up the stack.

Obviously this is just one scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one reason in his explanation: because doing so deprives you from the benefit of Resume (next).
Plus you won't know in which module the error happened.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use "bubble-up" part of error handling because errors should be handled & if it is known as to what to do, **if such an error occurs - is better known to procedure as to what to do *than* the calling procedure**.

```
Sub test()
  On Error GoTo e
  Dim c As Integer
  Dim d As Integer
  c = add(5, 0)
  d = divideWhichManagedItsOwnErrorHandling(5, 0)
  d = divide(5, 0)

  Exit Sub

e:
  MsgBox "error occurred somewhere for which I don't know what to do: " + Err.Description
End Sub

Function add(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
   add = a + b
End Function

Function divide(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
   divide = a / b 'if error occurs, it will "bubble-up" to the caller.
End Function

Function divideWhichManagedItsOwnErrorHandling(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim result As Integer
  result = a / b
  If Err.Number = 11 Then 'if divide by zero occurred, user must have passed 0 for b
    result = 0 ' return 0 if the divide by zero occurs. 
  End If
  divideWhichManagedItsOwnErrorHandling = result
End Function
```

Comment: a/0 isn't 0! You just swallowed a real error and returned a wrong result.

Comment: @jtolle: I am not discussing the result of division here. This is just to give an example of error handling & specifically, handling the error where it occurrs.

Comment: You need a better example then. That specific error shouldn't be handled in that way.