# "catch" error due to missing privileges?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following code inside a VBA-Script (inside an Excel[openxml]-Sheet):

```
  For Each Co In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("META").ChartObjects
        Co.Delete
    Next Co
```

When I open the Excel File the first time "Co.Delete" throws an "Access Denied"-Error ("You do not have enough privileges to complete this operation")

When I select another sheet and go back to the first sheet and THEN clicke the SAME button like before, calling the method this error is NOT thrown. It looks quite like a Excel-Bug to me.

I know there is no try...catch in VBA and I know I could just insert "`on error resume next`" but I just don't want to :)

Is there a different approach like a method "`if (Co.DeletionAllowed) Then`" ?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` + `If Err.Number<>0` *IS* the equivalent of try-catch in VBA. Why don't you want to use it? Ok, it isn't nearly as elegant, but it does the same thing. Can also use `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` with an `ErrorHandler:` block at the end of your procedure.

Comment: My point was more about being able to prevent the error from even happening. Would do the same on .net (where possible). I prefer to use try...catch only on unexpected errors.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are right; uncritically using `On Error Resume Next` on its own to swallow all errors indiscriminately is indeed bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to detect ahead of time whether you will get this error.

This would be the way to catch and handle the error:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    For Each Co In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("META").ChartObjects
        Co.Delete
    Next Co

    'rest of your procedure goes here...

    'Now here comes the bit that does the error handling -- equivalent to a catch block
ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Clean-up code goes here
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 12345 ' or whatever error number you are getting
        'Permission denied when deleting ChartObject. Ignore and skip to next statement.
        Resume Next ' or whatever else you want to do
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unexpected error! See Immediate window for detail.s"
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Source & ", Procedure lkjh of Module Module1", Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        'Or whatever else you want to do to log unexpected errors.
    End Select
    Resume ExitProcedure
    Resume
```

[Why that second `Resume`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432113/119775)