# On error along with message box in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In one of my code if I get an error i need to pop the file name with error and then resume next.Below is the code snippet i am trying to use but it is giving me error.
Can anyone help me

```
sourcefilename = File_list.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Set Baccha_Wbk = Wbk.Workbooks.Open(sourcefilename)
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
ErrMsg:    MsgBox ("Error in file" & sourcefilename ),On Error Resume Next
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it...

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sFile As String
    '~~> If you are doing this in Excel. then you don't need Wbk
    Dim Wbk As Excel.Application
    Dim Baccha_Wbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '
    '~~> Rest of the Code
    '

    sFile = File_list.Cells(i + 1, 1)

    If FileFolderExists(sFile) Then
        '~~> If you are doing this in Excel. then you don't need Wbk
        Set Baccha_Wbk = Wbk.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Else
        MsgBox "File Doesn't exists"
    End If

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. This is how you could do it:

```
sourcefilename = File_list.Cells(i + 1, 1)
On Error Resume Next 'Errors get swallowed without warning. Use sparingly.
Set Baccha_Wbk = Wbk.Workbooks.Open(sourcefilename)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox ("Error in file" & sourcefilename )
On Error Goto 0 'Back to normal: errors get thrown as usual
```

A more complete error handler could look like this:

```
Sub abcd()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    '[code...]

    sourcefilename = File_list.Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Set Baccha_Wbk = Wbk.Workbooks.Open(sourcefilename)

    '[more code...]

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Clean-up code goes here
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    'Deal with each of the expected errors
    Case 53 ' File not found
        MsgBox "File not found: " & sourcefilename
    Case 70 ' Permission denied
        MsgBox "Permission denied. Maybe you don't have permission to access this drive? " & sourcefilename
    'etc. etc.

    'Deal with unexpected errors
    Case Else
        UnexpectedError Err.Number, Err.Source & ", Procedure abcd of Module Module1", Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End Select
    Resume ExitProcedure
    Resume
End Sub
```

([Why the double `Resume` at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432113/119775))

along with this helper sub — customize as you like.

```
Public Sub UnexpectedError(ByVal lngNumber As Long, _
                           ByVal strSource As String, ByVal strDescription As String, _
                           ByVal strHelpfile As String, ByVal lngHelpContext As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox "[" & strSource & "]" & vbCrLf & "Run-time error '" _
         & CStr(lngNumber) & "':" _
         & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strDescription, vbExclamation, Application.Name, _
           strHelpfile, lngHelpContext
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Debug.Print "Case " & CStr(lngNumber) & " '" & strDescription
    'Debug.Assert False 'uncomment while developing
End Sub
```