# Run Sub before macro Ends like Finally block

Tags: vba, error-handling

Is there some VBA best practice to use something like 'before end' subroutines?

I am changing Excel's default configs when my macro starts, and before my macro reaches its 'end sub' line I am resetting the configs to its standards.
But what if some error occurs? Am I supposed to define 'On Error' treatment inside all subs to reset the configs to the standard properties?

Just for example, I am changing configs such as:

```
ScreenUpdating
DisplayStatusBar
Calculation
DisplayAlerts
```

Comment: I couldn't find a proper duplicate of this question, but you can see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23350327/3198973). By resuming at the `ExitSub:` label, you can ensure whatever necessary clean up code is executed.

Comment: This one looks like the duplicate you were looking for: [Do we need to create a error handler for each subroutine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149273/do-we-need-to-create-a-error-handler-for-each-subroutine)

Comment: I changed the Question tittle to better fit my purpose, and to better differentiate it from the one you suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Patterns For VBA Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, the best way is to define an `On Error Goto` line, in each method where it's needed, like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    On Error GoTo Finally ' Try
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Do your stuff here

Finally:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

This will ensure the things like `ScreenUpdating` get done even if there is an error. You can also add a catch block, like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    On Error GoTo Catch ' Try
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Do normal stuff here

    GoTo Finally
Catch:

' Do only error stuff here

Finally:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Generally speaking, `GoTo` is a hated practice, but for error catching, VBA kind of forces your hand.

Comment: Im accepting your answer, in combination with @ckuhn203 comment and this link i found [link]
So what im gonna do is use ckuhn's error handler, but restoring the default On Error treatment just after that.


[link]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038006/good-patterns-for-vba-error-handling

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure there is no such mechanism that is called *unconditionally* before exiting a function or a subroutine. You may have though error handlers (but these are executed *conditionally*; see the comment of [ckuhn203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3198973/ckuhn203) for an example).

However, there is such a mechanism for instances of Class Modules (i.e. for objects). When an object is destroyed (this happens when is not referenced anymore by any variable/storage), its `Class_Terminate` subroutine is called no-matter-what. If you can wrap your task in such an object that you discard immediately after you create it, you could <del>override</del> overwrite this subroutine to do the cleanup.

Comment: +1 I like this solution. As for discarding it immediately, you could use the `With` statement, E.g., 
`With new UtilityClass`
`.DoStuff()`
`End With`

Comment: Knocking after 6 years, can you please add code to this post / share reference to a code that implements this?